# Reason we always observe a single dot when a particle hits a detector screen?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

I am trying to determine whether this is simply a brute fact or does it tell us something deep about the nature of reality? Is there any particular reason we see a dot appear rather than a triangle or smiley  face or something else (goofy but hopefully gets the idea across). People have been saying it has something to do with interactions being local, but I can imagine the wavefunction of the particle interacting in a pattern other than a point without throwing out locality.

I know that some interpretations of QM believe that there is literally a point-like particle that moves around, but what about other interpretations where the wavefunction is all that exists (ie many-worlds)

Comment: When we see a dot, we infer it's one electron. When two, two. When a pattern, many. A CRT old fashioned TV monitor does that. What are you up to?

Comment: Let me say it another way. We can isolate a single electron and then shoot it at the screen. It's my understanding that since we are shooting just one electron, we will always see one dot appear on the screen. However, assuming that the electron's wavefunction has some physical reality, the electron will spread out between the gun and the screen. However, we will only ever see this spread out thing hit the screen at one location. I just want an intuition for "why" this happens. Of course it could just be a brute fact about how particles work, but I'm trying to think about it mechanistically.

Comment: I'm not quite asking about interpretations of QM either, since I accept that when we are *given* that the particles always hit at one location, the interpretations explain where the probability distribution comes from. But I'm more curious about why we see a dot appear at all. The only interpretation that I know addresses this is the pilot wave theory where the particle really is a little dot.

Comment: The die lands with only one face up, not two or more.

Comment: @CosmasZachos  So my question, as weird as it sounds, is why these are the faces of the die that nature has chosen.

Comment: Nobody knows "why". Nobody should expect to, in *this* SE.

Comment: I see what you're getting at...lol (is there a philosophy stack exchange)

Comment: Obviously I can answer that myself. Are the people there going to know enough physics? Meh worth a shot.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments:

> However, assuming that the electron's wavefunction has some physical reality, the electron will spread out between the gun and the screen.

This is the problem. The wavefunction is not measurable, and this is part of the [postulates of quantum mechanics.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) The postulates are the base of all  formalisms of quantum mechanics ( otherwise they are alternate theories to be tested).

$Ψ$  is not a quantity that can be measured. What is measured and compared to data is $Ψ^*Ψ$ , **the probability of finding the particle** at an (x,y,z,t). This means that a single event is not enough to test the QM model. One needs a number of events to see the wave like nature of the probability. See this [single electron at a time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) experiment.

Comment: But you will often hear proponents of many-worlds state that it is the simplest interpretation because all that exists is the wavefunction evolving under the Schrodinger Equation. I don't see how to reconcile this smooth evolution with the fact that measurement can only happen in these particular ways.

Comment: The many worlds are a "theory" that takes literally the quantum field theory  path integral calculations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation . If no extra assumptions are introduced, it is also based on the postulates, by mathematical construction.BUT they take things further when they assume reality in physical space and time of mathematical lines.It is not an interpretation,but anew theory, and has to be validated or falsified, maybe in the future.( at the moment I see it as metaphysics)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "they assume reality in physical space and time of mathematical lines"?

Comment: That the lines exist  in (x,y,z,t), new worlds, instead of mathematical models.It is as if I decide that because there is a mathematical function describing a satelite orbit, the orbit exists by itself in space and time.